# What do you think about the performance if I use all of width and height values in dimen.xml

Tags: android

What do you think about the performance if I use all of width and height values in dimen.xml

dimen.xml
    ...

```
...
<dimen name="wdp15">15dp</dimen>
<dimen name="wdp16">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="wdp17">17dp</dimen>
<dimen name="wdp18">18dp</dimen>
<dimen name="wdp19">19dp</dimen>
...
<dimen name="hdp224">224dp</dimen>
<dimen name="hdp225">225dp</dimen>
<dimen name="hdp226">226dp</dimen>
<dimen name="hdp227">227dp</dimen>
<dimen name="hdp228">228dp</dimen>
<dimen name="hdp229">229dp</dimen>

...
```

As mentioned above, I define all values such as width and height in dimen.xml
I want to cover all resolution of the devices, so I made dimen files as above in appropriate screen-resolution folder.

is this OK considering the performance?

Comment: You never notice any difference. Xml resouces saved in binary form and parsed very fast

Answer (score 0):

Using dimen.xml - it's android way. There is no performance issue. Additionally you have no chance if you want to make high quality app for different device resolution :)

Advice: use readable and understandable name for values like: start_screen__width, popup__button_text_size. And read about android styles and themes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I mean I used values of dimen.xml I mentioned above for all of width and height in layout xml files. For example, android:layout_width:@dimen/wdp20